# Can't connect to ssh due to host verification failed

Tags: ssh, mac-osx, ssh-keys, host, verification

I have an issue with connecting to my ssh hosts. 
I keep getting this message in verbose mode:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2, LibreSSL 2.4.1
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/me/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/me/.ssh/config line 4: Applying options for *.ta.local
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to <host_name> [<host_ip>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 4
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to >host_ip>:22 as 'me'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:+Wl92PcQ6xQSAtNdxvAeBWExxDXl6NM0M4i6dUEvVA0
The authenticity of host '<host_name> (<host_ip>)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:+Wl92PcQ6xQSAtNdxvAeBWExxDXl6NM0M4i6dUEvVA0.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
Host key verification failed.
```

FYI: in the pasted trace, I replaced username, host and ip...just in case someone is confused.

Here is my ssh_config:

```
Host *
    SendEnv LANG LC_*

# Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
```

I read a lot about that the host key may have changed since my last login. So I already tried removing the entries in the known_hosts file and still keep getting that error no matter what ssh server.

Any idea what I might got wrong here?

Further information: I recently updated mac os to sierra. Maybe it is related.

Comment: Is it an automated process that is trying to connect via SSH or are you doing it yourself?

Comment: I was doing it myself. Just solved the problem by passing StrictHostKeyChecking=no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may know, fingerprint changing can mean that you are being under a man in the middle attack, so take that in mind firstly.
From [What is a SSH key fingerprint and how is it generated?](https://superuser.com/questions/421997/what-is-a-ssh-key-fingerprint-and-how-is-it-generated):

> The fingerprint is based on the Host's Public key, usually based on "/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub" Generally its for easy identification/verification of the host you are connecting to.
>
> If the fingerprint changes, the machine you are connecting to has changed their public key. This may not be a bad thing(happens from re-installing ssh), but it could also indicate that you are connecting to a different machine at the same domain/IP(happens when you are connecting through something like load balancer) or that you are being targeted with a man-in-the-middle attack, where the attacker is somehow intercepting/rerouting your ssh connection to connect to a different host which could be snooping your user/pw.

So, if you are now sure that the server is secure, I'd suggest connecting manually and acepting the new fingerprint as it seems to be the easiest solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, that this is a common sign for a man in the middle attack. I can rule this one out, it is probably due to an attempt to create a self signed certificate earlier this week, that might have messed up something with my keys. As in the comment above, I solved it by disabling the host key check once. I gonna close the question, as it is not very useful for others, as my issue was self inflicted and kinda special. Anyhow, I gave you an upvote for explaining the mitm thing.

Comment: Okay, I can't close it after receiving an answer and there is no matching option for flagging it as closable. So, I let it as is, and accept your answer.